# Getting junk values while converting network stream to string

Tags: c#

I am using Telnet protocol in order to read a text file from the server PC. But when I try to convert network stream to sting, it is giving some junk values. What will be the issue here?

```
NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ns);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(ns);
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesread = tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize;
ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytesread);
string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I have tried to read the text file through command prompt. Using the following steps
1. Enabled telnet server in the server pc and client in my pc.
2. change telnet port in server pc to 24
3. Using telnet   command connect to server pc.
4. from telnet window> using type  display the content of the text file in command prompt.

Now I want to do the same from my c# code. I have written the following code:

```
TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
tcpclient.Connect(<ip address>, <port>);
NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ns);
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("type <file location>");
string returnd = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg);
ns.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new St
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesread = tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize;
ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytesread);reamWriter(ns);
string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

but my code is always giving some junk output like " ÿý%ÿûÿûÿý'ÿýÿý"

Comment: Try Base64 decoding of the stream sent by the server before trying to converting it into string.

Comment: Tried Base64 decoding but still the output is junk only.

Answer (score 0):

`ReceiveBufferSize` is the size of the receive buffer, but when you read, you don't always get a full buffer. The `Read` method returns the actual number of bytes that were read, you should use that to limit the part of the buffer you want to decode:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize];
int nRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize);
string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, nRead);
```

Comment: Above code help me to filter out the empty values in the buffer but still it is giving junk value for the decoded string.